how to hash a password in django while creating a user
here is my views from django project. how do i hash my password
@api_view(['POST'])
def register(request):
  data = request.data
  serializer = SignUpSerializers(data=data)
  if serializer.is_valid():
    if not CustomUser.objects.filter(email=data['email']).exists():
      user = CustomUser.objects.create(
        first_name = data['first_name'],
        last_name = data['last_name'],
        email = data['email'],
        username = data['username'],
        password = data['password']
      )
      return Response({
        'details':"User registered sucessfully."
      }, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response({
      'error':"Email already exists."
    }, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
  return Response(serializer.errors)

hasing while creating a user is better or while saving in model

You can hash your password by using make_password
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

@api_view(['POST'])
def register(request):
  data = request.data
  serializer = SignUpSerializers(data=data)
  if serializer.is_valid():
    if not CustomUser.objects.filter(email=data['email']).exists():
      user = CustomUser.objects.create(
        first_name = data['first_name'],
        last_name = data['last_name'],
        email = data['email'],
        username = data['username'],
        password = make_password(data['password'])
      )
      return Response({
        'details':"User registered sucessfully."
      }, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response({
      'error':"Email already exists."
    }, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
  return Response(serializer.errors)

